# Some Nearby Places returning "ZERO_RESULTS" for android

Tags: google-places-api

It seems some of the place types such as (night_club/taxi_stand/gas_station) are returning:

{

```
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
```

}

While others are having no issue at all

Here is an example for department store:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?&location=32.5548071,74.7962474&rankby=distance&keyword=department_store&key=YOUR_API_KEY

The documentation states it is all supported:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types

Answer (score 0):

This has been marked as a duplicate of:
https://issuetracker.google.com/35824648